# Random.nextFloat is not applicable for floats?

Tags: java, random

```
float minX = 50.0f;
float maxX = 100.0f;

Random rand = new Random();

float finalX = rand.nextFloat(maxX - minX + 1.0f) + minX;
```

"The method nextFloat() in the type Random is not applicable for the arguments (float)"

Um, what?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The [`nextFloat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextFloat()) method doesn't take an argument.  Call it, then scale the returned value over the range you want.

```
float minX = 50.0f;
float maxX = 100.0f;

Random rand = new Random();

float finalX = rand.nextFloat() * (maxX - minX) + minX;
```

Comment: @herpderp: No, it just returns a value between 0.0 and 1.0 that you can use as a handy scaling factor.

Comment: the link to the nextFloat documentation is broken. perhaps this one https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextFloat()

Comment: @JessevanMuijden Yes, that's the right one. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Random only return floats between 0 and 1.0 (no overloaded version like for integers): See the Javadocs here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextFloat()

I think you can do what you are intending with:

```
float finalX = (maxX - minX) * rand.nextFloat() + minX;
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is very clear, `nextFloat()` doesn't take any arguments. It'll give you a number between 0 and 1, and you'll need to use that in your calculation.

**edit: example**

```
private Random random = new Random();
public float nextFloat(float min, float max)
{
    return min + random.nextFloat() * (max - min)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should read like the following as others are suggesting.

```
float finalX = rand.nextFloat();
// do other stuff
```