# Generating Random.nextFloat() with parameter error

Tags: java

I am trying to generate a random float with this code.

```
 float rangeDuration2 = maxDuration - minDuration;
```

But for some reason java isnt letting me with this line as i would with .nextInt()

> The method nextFloat() in the type Random is not applicable for the arguments (float)

```
 float actualDuration2 = rand.nextFloat(rangeDuration2) + minDuration;
```

Anyway around this?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078157/random-nextfloat-is-not-applicable-for-floats

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
 float actualDuration2 = rand.nextFloat()*rangeDuration2 + minDuration;
```